# How to save the CPU percentage of a certain process into a variable in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, process, command, cpu, percentage

I have a small batch script here that gives me the percentage of a certain process (Server.exe in this example) and I have a weird bug where it cannot parse the command output to a variable.

Here is the full example:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ( 'wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime ^| find /N "Server"' ) DO SET Variable=%%A
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ( "%var%" ) do echo %%a
pause
```

And here is really the only part you need to pay attention to:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ( 'wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime ^| find /N "Server"' ) DO SET Variable=%%A
```

When this command is run it returns "Invalid GET Expression." when it should pass through with no flaw.  How can I fix this so that the for loop works and it saves the output to a variable?

P.S I know I could just write it to a text file, but that is very sloppy and I would prefer to do it this way.

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17554142/2098699).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write to a file, `FOR` command is just what you need.

I see two flaws in your code.

1. You need to escape the comma in the `wmic` command
2. If you have more than one `"SERVER"` instance and in case you want to later use `VARIABLE` for each one, then you need to use **delayed expansion**

so, your code might be..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ( 'wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name^,PercentProcessorTime ^| find /N "server"' ) DO (
   SET var=%%a
   for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b in ( "!var!" ) do echo %%b
)
```